# PHP Google Analytic V3 - Return child pages of pagePath

Tags: php, filtering, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to return all sub/child pages of a certain URL segment. I can do this easily using filters inside the official GA console, but can't seem to replicate it via the API

For example:

- http://example.com/fruit/apples
- http://example.com/fruit/oranges
- http://example.com/fruit/bananas
- http://example.com/vegetables/carrots

I'm trying to get the page views for all the different fruits and no vegetables.

I'm just not sure which combination of dimensions and filters to use to achieve this.

```
$data = $analytics->data_ga->get($analyticsViewId, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'filters'    => 'ga:pagePath==fruit/',
        'sort'       => '-ga:pageviews',
    ));
```

The above code works but will just return a single page (http://example.com/fruit) and not the child pages. Is filtering even the correct method here?

I've tried matching using something like

```
pagePath =@ /fruit/
```

Which does work, but sometimes returns odd results and feels a bit 'clumsy' for lack of a better word. It is also possible that  http://example.com/something/fruit/something-else may exist and it will require a lot of filtering server-side to weed out what isn't wanted.